# mp4 video loading forever and does not open of Samsung TV

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, vlc, codec

I have two mp4 files one is working on Samsung TV and the second one is not working, it keep loading forever

I have checked the codec of both and the are the same , the only change is the bitrate is different, could that be the reason of not being able to play the video on TV

and if yes how to solve t using vlc program or any ffmpeg code that convert it

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -n -i 16.mp4 -i 01.mp4` This command is only to get file info: its does not output a file. It will provide useful info about the inputs and your `ffmpeg` version. This info is required to provide an answer that you can copy and paste. Copy the **complete** log from that command. [Edit] your question and paste the complete log into your question. Ignore the `At least one output file must be specified error` in the log.

Comment: or get the output of the files with `ffprobe 16.mp4`

Comment: Also which one is working and which one isn't?